# Epoxy over cementboard

Tags: flooring, cement-board, epoxy

I have achieved fantastic results applying epoxy over the concrete floor in my basement apartment.

I am currently doing the kitchen in my main unit. My preferred flooring choice is stone tile because the pre-existing conditions make it possible without any unknown adaptation. But I've been flirting with the idea of epoxy.

The problem is that half of the surface ( *which has nothing underneath but ground*,) is concrete, and the other half (  *which goes over the basement* ) is usual wood construction consisting of  2x8 joists + 3/4" OSB, which I'm reinforcing with 1/2" plywood and 1/4" cement-board.

I know that epoxy can go easily over the concrete half but how about the cement-board?

Can I apply something over the cement-board, like self leveling compound, to cover the seams and screws and achieve a concrete-like surface that would equalize it with the concrete side so that I can apply the epoxy primer and then epoxy itself?

Answer (score 2):

Cement board isn't intended as a finished floor. It's not as dense as concrete. You'd find high heels and chair legs punching into it in short order, leaving you with a crumbly mess. Obviously you'd also have to tape all the seams and skim the screw holes, but you'd still have air voids across the entire surface to deal with.

I'd try epoxy over good (hardwood veneer?) plywood before cement board.

Answer (score 1):

Just based on what I have done outside I would say yes with certain caveats.

1. First you would need to use something like Durock which is outdoor rated.  If you used hardibacker, it would be too brittle.
2. You would need to create one continuous surface with the Durock.   So it would need to be installed over the concrete.  If not you would be dealing with a constant crack between it and your concrete floor.   Also there is a chance after the epoxy settles that you would have a slight ridge due to materials absorbed differently.
3. You would need to cover the seams - mesh and fill - just as you would before a tile job.
4. The epoxy would have to be installed pretty thick so there wasn't any wear layer being applied to the concrete board.

I don't see why it couldn't.  Durock makes primers and vapor retardant epoxies for their installs that I have used.   What is the difference of a sheet of tile or a few layers of epoxy?

On a side note - I would say this is more on the epoxy not the Durock.  I have used epoxy on outdoor islands right over durock.   Super easy!   Now is the epoxy that you want to walk on rated to be installed on this... I don't know.   However concrete board is really your only option as wood would have too many humidity changes to handle epoxy that would last more than one season.